# Does JSON Schema support choosing a string from a list in a separate object?

Tags: json, jsonschema

I would like to create a schema where the value of a string property links to the name of a property in a different part of the JSON object. For example:

```
{
  "configuration": {
    "sites": {
      "Site1": {
        "displayName": "Default Site",
        "connectionString": "Site1"
      },
      "Site2": {
        "displayName": "Site 2",
        "connectionString": "Site3"
      },
      "Site3": {
        "displayName": "Site 3",
        "connectionString": "Site3"
      }
    },
    "defaultSite": "GENBuild"
  },
  "conectionStrings": {
    "Site1": "",
    "Site2": "",
    "Site3": ""
  }
}
```

What I would like for the schema to enforce that the `connectionString` value of the site to match one of the property names in the `connectionStrings` map. Does JSON schema support a way to do this?

Here is my schema so far:

```
{
  "definitions":{
    
  },
  "$schema":"http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "$id":"https://example.com/object1657140793.json",
  "title":"Root",
  "type":"object",
  "required":[
    "configuration",
    "conectionStrings"
  ],
  "properties":{
    "configuration":{
      "$id":"#root/configuration",
      "title":"Configuration",
      "type":"object",
      "required":[
        "sites",
        "defaultSite"
      ],
      "properties":{
        "sites":{
          "$id":"#root/configuration/sites",
          "title":"Sites",
          "type":"object",
          "patternProperties":{
            "^Site[d]$":{
              "type":"object",
              "required":[
                "displayName",
                "connectionString"
              ],
              "properties":{
                "displayName":{
                  "title":"Display Name",
                  "type":"string",
                  "default":"",
                  "examples":[
                    "Default"
                  ],
                  "pattern":"^.*$"
                },
                "connectionString":{
                  "title":"Connection String",
                  "type":"string",
                  "default":"",
                  "examples":[
                    "Site1"
                  ],
                  "pattern":"^Site[d]$"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "defaultSite":{
          "$id":"#root/configuration/defaultSite",
          "title":"Default Site",
          "type":"string",
          "default":"",
          "examples":[
            "Site1"
          ],
          "pattern":"^Site[d]$"
        }
      }
    },
    "conectionStrings":{
      "$id":"#root/conectionStrings",
      "title":"Conection Strings",
      "type":"object",
      "patternProperties":{
        "^Site[d]$":{
          "type":"string",
          "default":"",
          "examples":[
            ""
          ],
          "pattern":"^.*$"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with JSON Schema or of the box, but I have an [extension vocabulary](https://json-everything.net/json-schema#a-vocabulary-for-accessing-data-stored-in-json) implemented for JsonSchema.Net: [JsonSchema.Net.Data](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JsonSchema.Net.Data/).

Comment: Thank for the reply! In this case I'm configuring an AWS JSON Schema to validate JSON in an AWS AppConfig deployment profile. Not sure if I can apply that there.